# Multi tenant support for nodejs using keycloak

Tags: node.js

i m using AngularJS and nodeJS application for UI development.
Using the Keycloak for user authentication purpose with the help of keycloak-connect libraray.
with this everything works fine.

But i want to achieve multi tenancy in keycloak,
Based on a particular realm i should be able to redirect to a particular keycloak login page.

Can we load keycloak.json file dynamically based on a particular realm using nodeJS
Are there any library available to achieve the same.

Thank you,
Vinay

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: nope, planning to authenticate separately.

Comment: Use this GitHub project  that supports Keycloak Node.js Adapter With Support for multiple realms https://github.com/devsu/keycloak-nodejs-multirealm